# SatelliteMenu error cannot find activity_main in setContent view

Tags: java, android, menu, satellite

Solution at this link was not helpful, or explain that

if i add

```
SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu);
```

then in

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

it says cannot resolve `activity_main` id

added library, and change the XML package name
before in other project it was working but now not working in any project
same error